# how to capture data through web service (php) sql query select with condition from ios iphone sdk

Tags: iphone, mysql, objective-c, ios, web-services

I have the following php file:

```
<?php 
$username="root";
$database="testdb";
mysql_connect(localhost,$username);
$user=$_GET["user"];
$password=$_GET["password"];
$query="SELECT documento FROM person WHERE user='".$user." and  password ='".$password."'";

$result=mysql_query($query) or die (mysql_error("error "));

$num=mysql_numrows($result);

mysql_close();

$rows=array();

while($r=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){

$rows[]=$r;

 }
 echo json_encode($rows);

 ?>
```

to retrieve the information achieved by the following functions but the example did not have the php input conditions and parameters was `select * from person`  here the functions
 based in http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=endscreen&v=IQcLngIDf9k&NR=1

```
-(void) getData:(NSData *) data{

   NSError *error;

   json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

}

-(void) start {
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:kGETUrl];

   NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];

   [self getData:data];

}
```

now as the sql statement has input parameters is not as code and tried something like this [A Simple PHP/MySQL Web Service for iOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6156411/a-simple-php-mysql-web-service-for-ios) but I can not accommodate what I need.

Comment: shouldn't you use the POST[] value for the user and password? i am not sure about this but i am curious..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass the parameters in the string. Here is an example

```
-(void) start {
    NSString *user     = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"exampleuser"];
    NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"examplepassword"];
    NSString *urlstr   = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://myserver.com/myphpfile.php?user=%@?password=%@", user, password];
    NSURL    *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr];
    NSData   *data     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
    [self getData:data];
}
```

As it is password and user it normally is better to use POST instead of GET because then it is not part of the URL which is visible. With POST you can hide it if you have a https line. But I think this is not your main concern right now. The above should work.

Answer (score 0):

I made some change in Hollfeder's code and it worked perfectly :)

```
-(void) start {
NSString *user     = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"exampleuser"];
NSString *password = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"examplepassword"];
NSString *urlstr   = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"http://myserver.com/myphpfile.php?user=%@&password=%@", user, password];
NSString *urlstr_encoded = [urlstr stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSURL    *url      = [NSURL URLWithString:urlstr_encoded];
NSData   *data     = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
[self getData:data];
```

}